# Showing process completed but no output is coming up

Tags: java, jcreator

I am trying to create a program that accepts two numbers and outputs the smallest digit in one number that is larger than the other number(for example, given 4687 and 5, the program should output 6).

The problem that I'm having is that when I compile the program, even though I'm getting no errors, after inputting the two numbers, no output is being shown. The cursor just continues blinking where it is. This is the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Numbers {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int smallest = 10;
    int num;
    System.out.printf("Enter a value for n: \n");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Enter a value for num: \n");
    num = in.nextInt();
    int ch = System.in.read();
    while (ch>n && ch<smallest) {
            smallest=ch;
            ch = System.in.read();
    }
    System.out.printf("Smallest number that is larger is %d", smallest);
}
}
```

Comment: There are additional reads after the two numbers. It's not just waiting for input?

Comment: What are you expecting from `System.in.read()`?

Comment: I thought that using that would run through each digit in the variable num but that's where I was wrong. I need to find another way to run through the number using loops somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your program just fine.  What you are experiencing is probably just that the program is waiting on input from you that you do not expect to enter.

- It's expecting *three* inputs from the user, is that how you ran it?
- Did you remember to hit the enter button on your keyboard after you input the numbers?

Here's a sample output from your program:

```
Enter a value for n: 
100
Enter a value for num: 
2
0 // <-- This value corresponds to your program prompting for int ch = System.in.read(); 
Smallest number that is larger is 10D
```

**HINT**:  You probably want to convert the value entered for n to a `String`, then use the `toCharrArray()` method on `String` so you can traverse each character, like what you're doing in the `while` loop.

Try something like:

```
for(char ch : Integer.toString(n).toCharArray()) { 
// rest of your while loop logic

}
```

Comment: Oh I think my problem is with the logic. When I used ch = System.in.read(); I thought that would have run through each character in the variable num one by one and perform the instruction in the while loop. Is it that I need to use a for loop or something to run through each digit in num?